# Сборка проекта Qt компилятором Intel C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, qt, компилятор, сборка, intel

Здравствуйте!
Имеется Qt 5.5.0, собранный на msvc2012. Надо в QT Creator подключить компилятор Intel C++ Compiler 2015 и собрать проект Qt. Добавляю компилятор, задаю параметры сборки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При попытке сборки проекта получаю следующий вывод:

```
14:30:18: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled...
14:30:18: Запускается: «C:\Qt_msvc\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe» C:\Qt_msvc\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\untitled\untitled.pro -r "CONFIG+=debug"
14:30:18: Процесс «C:\Qt_msvc\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe» завершился успешно.
14:30:18: Запускается: «C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\bin\ia32\icl.exe» 
Intel(R) C++ Compiler XE for applications running on IA-32, Version 15.0.0.108 Build 20140726
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 28-jun-2017 UTC.
icl: command line error: no files specified; for help type "icl /help"
14:30:19: Процесс «C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\bin\ia32\icl.exe» завершился с кодом 1.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled (комплект: intelcomp15)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
14:30:19: Прошло времени: 00:01.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что делаю неправильно. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Предполагаю что могут быть проблемы  при использовании qmake собранного отличным компиллером, он жестко прописывает некоторые пути. Кроме этого возможно ваш компилятор тупо отказывается работать icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 28-jun-2017 UTC. Вы им можете простенький hello world собрать из консоли? И сомневаюсь что Вы сможете собрать ваш проект с intel компилятором с библиотеками от MSVC

Answer (score 0):

Ответ тут очевиден:

> icl: command line error: no files specified; for help type "icl /help"

судя по всему проект не до конца настроен.

Comment: А как его настроить? Или чего не хвавтает?